# Why is an object needed to refer to a class member inside of a static method?

Tags: java, oop, static, static-methods

Compare the way I print the value of the members of this class, in the static method (main) v/s a non-static method (the print method). In the static method, I need to use an object of this class, whereas, in the non-static method, I can refer to the class members directly.

I understand that the scope of static is class-wide, and is not tied to an object. Could someone elaborate a bit further on why I need to use an object in the static method, and it's not needed in a non-static method.

```
public class TreeDriver {
    Tree tree;
    TreeNode p;

    public TreeDriver() {
        tree = new Tree();
        p =null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeDriver obj = new TreeDriver();

        obj.print(obj.tree.root, obj.p);
    }

    public void print(TreeNode nodeA, TreeNode nodeB)
    {
        System.out.print(nodeA.val + ", " + nodeB.val);
        System.out.print(tree.root.val + ", " + p.val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print` method isn't a static method, so it can only be called on an instance of the `TreeDriver` class (i.e. it can't be called from the class directly, like `TreeDriver.print(...)`)

From your perspective, there's no way around this really, as you're accessing the instance variables `p` and `tree` in your method.

I would add that it'd probably make more sense if you split out your driver methods (e.g. `main(String[] args)` away from your data model (i.e. the instance variables and the `print` method).

Answer (score 0):

Static methods do not need an object instance to be called.

In your above example, another class could call your main function like so.

```
TreeDriver.main(args);
```

Notice that TreeDriver is not an instantiated object. Contrast this with how a different class would need to call print.

```
TreeDrvier newTreeDrvier = new TreeDriver();
newTreeDriver.print(nodeA, nodeB);
```

You need an *instance* of the TreeDriver object. Members are defined for an instance of the class, not for the class itself, unless the member itself is static, which in that case would make it a [class variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you don't need an instance to call a static method. There's really nothing more to say about "why" than just "that's the definition of a static method."

A non-static method is associated with a specific instance. As an analogy, if I tell you to start the car, you go start a *specific* car - you can't just grab the key and turn it in mid-air and expect it to "work."